# jasmine-node with request - testing endpoints that redirect don't follow redirects

Tags: node.js, redirect, jasmine-node, node-request

Even when adding `followAllRedirects` only changes `response.statusCode` from `302` to `200` but the `body` remains the content of the previous response and all the other properties of the `response` reflect the old one.

Note: I'm doing these in tests using grunt.

Any reason why redirects aren't followed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's written in the docs https://github.com/mikeal/request#requestjar:

> Cookies are disabled by default (else, they would be used in
>   subsequent requests). To enable cookies, set jar to true (either in
>   defaults or options).

```
var request = request.defaults({jar: true})
request('http://www.google.com', function () {
  request('http://images.google.com')
})
```